# How do I put a statement and input on the same line

Tags: python

I am new to coding and learning basics, I am creating my first project but I have a problem
my code is

```
name = input('what is your name? ')
print('hi ' + name)
yea =input('what is your birth year? ')
age = 2020 - int(yea)
print(age)
```

I want the output to be

What is your name?
tan
What is your birth year?
2000
You are 20 years old

But I can't find a way to put "you are --- years old" with age

How my code can be to get the output I needed

Answer (score 1):

Use f-strings

```
print(f'You are {age} years old')
```

Or normal string concatenation:

```
print('You are ' + str(age) + ' years old')
```

Note: you can only `+` concatenate strings with other strings, that's why the `str(age)` is required

Answer (score -1):

#### String format

Old version:

```
name = input('what is your name? ')
print('hi ' + name)
yea =input('what is your birth year? ')
age = 2020 - int(yea)
print('You are %d years old' % age)
```

Using `.format`:

```
name = input('what is your name? ')
print('hi ' + name)
yea =input('what is your birth year? ')
age = 2020 - int(yea)
print('You are {0} years old'.format(age))
```

For up python version 3.6 :

```
name = input('what is your name? ')
print('hi ' + name)
yea =input('what is your birth year? ')
age = 2020 - int(yea)
print(f'You are {age} years old')
```

#### Other

Or use `print()` with `,`:

```
name = input('what is your name? ')
print('hi ' + name)
yea =input('what is your birth year? ')
age = 2020 - int(yea)
print('You are', age 'years old')
```

Or use `print()` with `+`:

```
name = input('what is your name? ')
print('hi ' + name)
yea =input('what is your birth year? ')
age = 2020 - int(yea)
print('You are '+age+' years old')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print("Your name is %s and your age is %d." %(name,int(age)))
```

Comment: You don't have to convert age into int. it's already int